# Relation has_many/belongs_to PG::UndefinedColumn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I get this error when I do this:

```
user.owned_tipsters
```

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERREUR:  column tipsters.user_id does not exist
```

My code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :owned_tipsters, class_name: 'Tipster', inverse_of: :owner
end

class Tipster < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :owned_tipsters
end
```

If you can help me to know where does this error, I would thank you

Boris
Thx

Comment: Did you create something foregin_key for `users` in `tipsters`?

Comment: I have added the fields 'owner_id' in tipsters but I always error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add foreign_key in you `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_tipsters, class_name: 'Tipster', inverse_of: :owner, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
end
```

Comment: thank you a lot, but normally we do not have to specify the 'foreign_key' ?

Comment: @BorisBresciani You need the `:foreign_key` option when your names don't match the conventions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key